# Implement siginterrupt() using sigaction()?

Tags: c, linux

Implement `siginterrupt()` using `sigaction()` with one example.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void helpAndLeave(const char *progname, int status);
void pexit(const char *fCall);
int interrupt(int, int);
void handler(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 1) {
        helpAndLeave(argv[0], EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* struct sigaction act;
       act.sa_handler = &handler;
     */

    interrupt(2,1);
//  while(1);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void helpAndLeave(const char *progname, int status) {
    FILE *stream = stderr;

    if (status == EXIT_SUCCESS) {
        stream = stdout;
    }

    fprintf(stream, "Usage: %s", progname);
    exit(status);
}

void pexit(const char *fCall) {
    perror(fCall);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int interrupt(int signal, int flag) {

    printf("interrupt block\n");
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &handler;

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &act) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (flag) {
        act.sa_flags &= ~SA_RESTART;
    } else {
        act.sa_flags &= SA_RESTART;
    }

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("sigaction error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("exit occur\n");
    while(1);
}

void handler(int signal) {
    printf("OMG, INTERRUPTION!!!!!\n");
}
```

here it is not going to handler function when i enter (ctrl+c).

so please give some solution to this.

you can find this example on the [this link](https://github.com/bernardoamc/C/blob/master/c20/siginterrupt.c).

Comment: The first time you call `sigaction`, it's overwriting `act`, so your assignment to `act.sa_handler` is lost.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &act)` it overwrites `act` with the current handler for the signal. So your assignment to `act.sa_handler` is overwritten. You need to do that assignment **after** the call, not before it.

And the way to turn a bit on in a bit mask is with `|`, not `&`, so

```
    act.sa_flags &= SA_RESTART;
```

should be:

```
    act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
```

So the whole function should be:

```
int interrupt(int signal, int flag) {

printf("interrupt block\n");
struct sigaction act;

if (sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &act) == -1) {
    return -1;
}

act.sa_handler = &handler;

if (flag) {
    act.sa_flags &= ~SA_RESTART;
} else {
    act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
}

if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) == -1) {
    printf("sigaction error\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("exit occur\n");
while(1);
}
```